# Run command only once if any items in a list are True (Ansible)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'd like to stop Nginx just once if any of the items in a list are `True`.

Because multiple items in the list could be `True`, I only want to stop Nginx on the first and then not run this command again.

At a later point in the script I will use the same logic to start Nginx again.

```
- name: Nginx is temporarily shutting down
  command: sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
  when:
    - item == True
  with_items: "{{ saved_results_list }}"
```

Is there a way to only run this if an item in the list is `True`, but not multiple times?

Comment: @techraf why didnt you edit it out asap (python tag)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop here, it's enough to use the `in` operator:

```
- name: Nginx is temporarily shutting down
  command: sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
  when: True in saved_results_list
```

Answer (score 1):

If it has little cost to get all items a once you can use the [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function.

```
if any(items):
    stop_nginx()
```

If not you can use break to stop iteration.

```
for i in get_data(): 
    if i:
         stop_nginx()
         break
```

If you have many condition use a flag like this:

```
nginx_stopped = False
for i in get_data():
    if not nginx_stopped and should_stop_ngingx(i):
         stop_nginx()
         nginx_stopped = True

   #other_conditional branchings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list like `booleans = [True, False, True, False, False]`, you can use special python functions `any()` and `all()` to test whether any or all of the elements in the list are True.

```
> any(booleans)
> True
>
> all(booleans)
> False
```

You can use this to shut down Nginx like:

```
import os

if any(saved_results_list):
    os.system("sudo systemctl stop nginx.service")
```